# каждые 3 элемента через три

Tags: css, css3

Добрый вечер всем. Есть родитель у него много детей

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>//green
    <div class="child"></div>//green
    <div class="child"></div>//green
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>//green
    <div class="child"></div>//green
    <div class="child"></div>//green
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>//green
    <div class="child"></div>//green
    //и т. д.
</div>
```

как с помощью css сделать так, чтоб каждые 3 элемента через три были зелеными?

Comment: вот еще такой вариант - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/n49qyht7/

Comment: для тестирования можно использовать это - http://nth-test.com

Comment: @soledar10 да всё оказалось намного легче чем я думал.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я только это придумал

```
.child {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 30px;    
    background-color: #CCCCCC;    
    margin: 2px;
}
.parent div:nth-child(6n-3), .parent div:nth-child(6n-4), .parent div:nth-child(6n-5) {
    background-color: #00CC00;    
}
```

Пример тут http://jsfiddle.net/046xsfLk/

Comment: Вы крутой! Спасибо!)