# Как с помощью nth-child выбрать такую последовательность элементов?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Мне нужно выбрать такие элементы:
каждый 1, 7, 14...
2, 8, 15...
3, 9, 16...
4, 10, 17
Запутался в терминологии формул, спасайте

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [каждые 3 элемента через три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/441775/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b5-3-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8)

Comment: @Visman по-моему в данном случае не всё так просто

Comment: @Visman, это не дубликат...

Comment: У автора вопроса кривое условие `1, 7, 14... 
2, 8, 15... 
3, 9, 16... 
4, 10, 17... 
5, 11, 18... 
6, 12, 19... 
7, 13, 20...`

Comment: @Visman а может дальше продолжать этот ряд просто не нужно?)

Comment: Автор, уточните пожалуйста, что вам нужно и некривое ли условие

Comment: @andreymal, если дальше продолжать не надо, то пусть перечислит в css всех детей, которые имеются.

Comment: @Visman, не кривое. К примеру: ест переменные i = 6 и a = 1; И мы выполняем следующие действия: var a = a + i; i = i + 1; return a. Примерно так на JS

Comment: Хотя Yuri не автор вопроса... Вдруг он тоже не угадал?) Автор, отзовитесь!

Comment: @andreymal, Вы на числа посмотрите...

Comment: @Yuri посмотрел, ряд можно продолжить как `7 14 21 28`, а `1` возможно просто исключение. Я чуть не написал ответ, который делает именно так, но потом передумал

Comment: @andreymal, ваш скрипт бы не подошёл ко второму варианту, а таком случае

Comment: @Yuri `8 15 22 29` и `2` как исключение, всё подходит :)

Comment: @andreymal, с вашей логикой в мою школу на математику...

Comment: @Yuri я тест на логику Войнаровского на 30 баллов из 30 прошёл :D Без автора нельзя определить, кто из всех отписавшихся прав

Comment: @andreymal, а автор посмотрел на все это и ушел ни чего не сказав.

Comment: Не могу придумать такой алгоритм на чистом CSS

Answer (score 2):

Для последовательностей

> 1, 7, 14, 21...
>   2, 8, 15, 22...
>   3, 9, 16, 23...

Шаг 7; 1,2,3 - исключения - добавляем исключения вручную в css

```css
ul li:nth-child(1),
ul li:nth-child(7n+7) {  
  background: #F00;
}

ul li:nth-child(2),
ul li:nth-child(7n+8) { 
  background: #0F0;
}

ul li:nth-child(3),
ul li:nth-child(7n+9) { 
  background: #00F;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li><li>13</li><li>14</li><li>15</li><li>16</li><li>17</li><li>18</li><li>19</li><li>20</li><li>21</li><li>22</li><li>23</li><li>24</li><li>25</li><li>26</li>
</ul>
```

Для последовательностей

> 1, 7, 14, 22...
>   2, 8, 15, 23...
>   3, 9, 16, 24...

Имеем дело с [параболой](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cubic%20fit%20%7B%7B0,%201%7D,%20%7B1,%207%7D,%20%7B2,%2014%7D,%20%7B3,%2022%7D%7D), которую на чистом css не пропишешь, потому есть вариант с js:

```js
var rows = [
  {
    color: '#F00',
    formula: function(i) { return 0.5*i*i + 5.5*i + 1}
  },
  {
    color: '#0F0',
    formula: function(i) { return 0.5*i*i + 5.5*i + 2}
  },
  {
    color: '#00F',
    formula: function(i) { return 0.5*i*i + 5.5*i + 3}
  }
];
rows.forEach(function(r) {
  var css = "";
  for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    css += (css? ',' : '') + 'ul li:nth-child(' + r.formula(j) + ')'
  }
  css += '{background:' + r.color + ';}';
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.innerText = css;
  document.body.appendChild(style);
});
```

```html
<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li><li>13</li><li>14</li><li>15</li><li>16</li><li>17</li><li>18</li><li>19</li><li>20</li><li>21</li><li>22</li><li>23</li><li>24</li><li>25</li><li>26</li></ul>
```

Или на [SASS](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXaBmB)

Answer (score 0):

Оно?

```css
ul li:nth-child(6n+1) {  
  color: red;
}

ul li:nth-child(6n+2) {  
  color: green;
}

ul li:nth-child(6n+3) {  
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>23</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: У вас 1 7 13, а надо 1 7 14

Comment: 1 + 6 = 7, 7 + 7 = 14, 14 + 8 = 22 и т. д. Вот что ему нужно

Comment: @andreymal я думаю в данном случае это была опечатка и неправильная математика

Answer (score 0):

```css
   

ul li:nth-child(7n) {  
  color: red;
}

ul li:nth-child(7n+1) {  
  color: green;
}

ul li:nth-child(7n+2) {  
  color: blue;
}

ul li:nth-child(1) {
color: red;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) {
color: green;
}

ul li:nth-child(3) {
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>23</li>
</ul>
```